# How to add authorization to RazorPages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have looked at the current [official Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization) and was unable to find anything properly covering how to handle authorization for RazorPages.

I figured out that you can add the `AuthorizeAttribute` to the `PageModel` like so:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

[Authorize]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    ...
}
```

I don't want to repeat this for every page. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure authorization under the `ConfigureServices` method. Here is an example :

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/MembersOnly");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");

        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Pages/Admin", "Admins"); // with policy
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Pages/Admin/Login"); // excluded page

        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Public"); // just for completeness
    });
```

*The example above is extended from an example [provided in the official repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/bac68ba3c225b116d5be5ac1a1383d6bad053bf6/test/WebSites/RazorPagesWebSite/Startup.cs).*

The `AuthrorizeFolder` will restrict access to the entire folder, whereas the `AuthorizePage` would be restricting access based on the individual page. The `AllowAnonymousToFolder` and `AllowAnonymousToPage` doing the opposite, accordingly.

For specific documentation on the above, **as of today, the documentation is still being completed.** However, you can read about the progress of it and track it here https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/4281