# Redirect to login page when click the tab

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm very new in ASP.Net Core. 
Let say I have three tabs such as Home, contact and about.
The user can only access contact and about page if they are login. Otherwise, they cannot access the page. My question is, if the user is not login yet, how to redirect to the login page if they click the Contact or about tab?

Comment: When you click on the tab, is it a normal GET request to those action methods ? If yes you can check it there and redirect the user using the standard pattern.

Comment: You could decorate your controller or action with the `Authorize` attribute. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you go into the answer, it might be to your benefit to read through the great documentation available at the [official Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple).

As a simple solution, I would suggest you add authorization by using the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

If your project is using **MVC**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if your project is using **RazorPages**

```
[Authorize]
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you want to go further in-depth with authorization for RazorPages you can see my other answer for a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881927/3645638